# Проблема с открытием картинки из sqlite на python

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot, sqlalchemy

Не могу разобраться с проблемой. Суть такова: телеграм бот на python3 с использованием SQLalchemy, pytelegrambotapi и bd sqllite через sqlliteStudio. Работаю в pycharm. Код для вывода продуктов из bd:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, String, Integer, Float, Boolean, ForeignKey, BLOB 
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref
from models.category import Category
from data_base.dbcore import Base

class Products(Base):
# название таблицы
__tablename__ = 'products'

# поля таблицы
id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
name = Column(String, index=True)
title = Column(String)
price = Column(Float)
quantity = Column(Integer)
is_active = Column(Boolean)
category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
photo = Column(BLOB)

# для каскадного удаления данных из таблицы
category = relationship(
    Category,
    backref=backref('products',
                    uselist=True,
                    cascade='delete,all'))

def __repr__(self):
  
    return f"{self.name} {self.title} {self.price} {self.photo}"
```

Скриншот bd:
[image]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что делаю не так? Как вывести картинку?

Comment: А зачем вы выводите байты картинки в `repr`? Смотрите `return f"{self.name} {self.title} {self.price} {self.photo}`

Comment: Вам нужен метод отправки фото, в него и передавать картинку. Не знаю может ли pytelegrambotapi напрямую массив байт передавать, возможно, ему нужно будет передавать `io.BytesIO`, в который вы и положите массив байт

Comment: лучше в базе хранить путь до изображения

Comment: Т.е. думаю как-то так будет: `bot.send_photo(m.chat.id, BytesIO(product.photo), caption=f'{product.name} {product.title} {product.price}')`. Значение `caption` можно и из `str(product)` брать, если убрат из `__repr__` картинку

Comment: @gil9red, тогда полностью переписывать придется.

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin, ругается на encoding при чтении

Comment: @VladimirAbramov, а что там переписывать? Поменять `__repr__` (это не обязательно) и вместо отправки текста сделать отправку картинки

Comment: @gil9red разобрался, спасибо огромное :)

Comment: @VladimirAbramov, вы молодец :) Оформите, пожалуйста, самостоятельно ответ :)